# AJAX request get's called twice because of an interval

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval, clearinterval

I've a problem with my interval function. This is my function:

```
let data = {
    action: "verify_status",
};

let interval = setInterval( function () {
    if ( new Date().getTime() - startTime > 600000 ) {
        alert( "Error: Timed out!" );
        clearInterval( interval );
    }

    jQuery.post( ajax_url, data, function () {
    } ).success( function () {
        clearInterval( interval );
        successFunction();
    } ).fail( function ( response ) {
        if ( response.status === 500 ) {
            clearInterval( interval );
        }
    } );
}, 5000 );
```

My problem is now the following: The interval starts an AJAX request, which now runs in parallel. This is fine as long as the request fails with `HTTP 400`.

But if it runs successfully, my `successFunction()` is called. Unfortunately the interval continues running outside. As a result my `successFunction()` is called twice and sometimes three times, although I interrupt the execution with `clearInterval()`. Does anyone have an idea how I can do this better?

Comment: If you don't want the requests to fire in parallel, then don't use an interval. Instead, use a timeout which only runs once. When the AJAX request completes, set a new timeout to trigger the next one. That's a much better way to ensure that there's no overlap

Comment: you should use some recoursive function instead

Comment: @ADyson Thats an idea. How can I do this? Can you give me an example?

Comment: @Nico What do you exactly mean with this? Not sure how to understand it

Comment: @Mr.Jo I added an answer below containing an example of the concept, just as I described in my comment. Sorry if the idea wasn't clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want the requests to fire in parallel, then don't use an interval. Instead, use a timeout which only runs once. When the AJAX request completes, set a new timeout to trigger the next one. That's a much better way to ensure that there's no overlap.

Something like this:

```
setTimeout(runAjax, 5000);

function runAjax()
{
  if (new Date().getTime() - startTime > 600000) {
    alert( "Error: Timed out!" );
  }

  jQuery.post(ajax_url, data)
    .success(function () 
    {
      successFunction();
      setTimeout(runAjax, 5000);
    })
    .fail( function ( response ) {
      setTimeout(runAjax, 5000);
    });    
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to pass attributes to the function?

Comment: yes, if you wrap it inside another anonymous callback e.g. `setTimeout(function() { runAjax(someParameter); }, 5000);`. But you didn't specify that in your question, so I didn't include that.

Comment: Is it possible to call the function again from inside with all parameters passed at the first call from outside?

Comment: Sorry I'm not quite sure what you mean by that. Can you give a clearer explanation and/or example please

Comment: So when I call the function first, I'm running this command `setTimeout(function() { runAjax(someParameter); }, 5000);`. Now inside the function on success or fail, I need to call it again. Can I do it the same way by giving the function it's own parameters?

Comment: Yes, no problem to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You cleared the interval with the name verifyPaymentInterval on success. Try clearing the one with the name "interval" as well.

Comment: Copy issue. Made it a bit more abstract for this question. This causes no problem at all. The problem is the running interval outside of the AJAX function that calls is every 5 seconds. The thing is that I don't know how to make it better.